# 6 month old baby sleeps 30 minutes in a stroller

Tags: sleep, stroller

My baby started to sleep only 30 minutes in a stroller. The rest of the time he looks around or just looks at me. It doesn't matter if a stroller is moving or standing in place.

Can I help him sleep longer? I'm wondering if he doesn't sleep because he is not comfortable in the stroller (it doesn't fully recline - uppa baby vista)? Or he is just too curious about the singing birds, cars and other outside noises?
(At home he sleeps from 45 minutes, up to 1.5 hours)

thank you

Comment: Our LO started having 30 minute naps when she was 4 months old. She either sleeps exactly 30 minutes or 1,5-2h. In our case it doesn't matter whether she's sleeping in a stroller or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By six months you should not be using the stroller for sleep, at least by design. It's not a problem if the child does sleep in it, but don't focus on the length and don't use them for primary naps. Half an hour is plenty for a catnap; if you are looking for a full nap, put the child in his or her crib.

By that age, most children are large enough that the stroller is not very comfortable to sleep in.  Many children like to roll some during sleep, which is not possible in an upright stroller. Further, the neck position is not ideal upright.

Finally, yes, your child is interested in things outside more and more. That undoubtedly contributes to the child wanting to look around and not sleep.

Comment: thank you. so how do you advice to put baby to sleep when you are out of home at friend's house for example?

Comment: I try to plan around naps such that naps are at home, or just don't worry about it too much.  If the baby is very sleepy, and away from home, then she'll fall asleep in the stroller and get her half hour nap - and usually that half hour will be good enough to help her be in a good mood.